oData Service is called after columns change
short one: I have a smart table which is bind to an oData service. This works fine.
But when I add new columns to the view the oData service is called once again.
The columns where already populated before so there is no need to have a call again.
Any chance to avoid this behaviour?
Thanks Sven

The service is called again because SmartTable adds the $select parameter in the call only requesting the columns you see by default. So, if you make one hidden column visible you need an extra call to fetch that column.
You might try to bind the SmartTable using One-time binding but then all rows will be fetched as well.
You might also use beforeRebind event to add properies on the search parameter.
onBeforeRebindTable: function(oEvent) {
    var oBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
    if (oBindingParams.parameters.select.search("PropertyFoo") < 0) {
        oBindingParams.parameters.select += ",PropertyFoo";
    }

See also question 7 from SmartTable FAQ  - How do I get data for custom columns (icons, formatters etc.) that are not part of the columns/binding (select = 'ColA,ColB,foo,bar') of the SmartTable control?
